# Nested Dictionary from CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a CSV that is formatted this way, notice there are multiple names of the same image.:

| image | id | name | xMin | xMax | yMin | yMax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp | 1 | Scratch | 604 | 893 | 230 | 413 |
| 858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp | 2 | Dent | 921 | 1146 | 720 | 857 |
| 858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp | 1 | Dent | 343 | 2323 | 334 | 343 |

I'm trying to write a function to read this CSV into a nested dictionary that uses the column names as keys. If there are multiple names with same image, it will create a nested dictionary What I have so far is this:

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator
import json
with open('out1.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, dialect='excel', skipinitialspace=True)
    new_dict = {}
    for group, records in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter('image')):
        new_dict[group] = list(records)
json_object = json.dumps(new_dict, indent = 4)
print(json_object)
```

What I am getting is as follows:
`

```
{
"858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp": [
    {
        "image": "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Scratch",
        "xMin": "604",
        "xMax": "893",
        "yMin": "230",
        "yMax": "413"
    },
    {
        "image": "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp",
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Dent",
        "xMin": "921",
        "xMax": "1146",
        "yMin": "720",
        "yMax": "857"
    }
],
"858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp": [
    {
        "image": "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Dent",
        "xMin": "343",
        "xMax": "2323",
        "yMin": "334",
        "yMax": "343"
    }
]
```

}

`

and the output should be like this for the same image it should create nested dictionary:

`

```
{
  "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Scratch",
      "xMin": 604,
      "xMax": 893,
      "yMin": 230,
      "yMax": 413
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Dent",
      "xMin": 921,
      "xMax": 1146,
      "yMin": 720,
      "yMax": 857
    },
  ],
"858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Dent",
      "xMin": 343,
      "xMax": 2323,
      "yMin": 334,
      "yMax": 343
    }],
}
```

`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually I need a nested dictionary mainly that converts the CSV based on the image column. I also have included the should be nested output. But the code I wrote is not giving the desired output

Comment: What is wrong with what you have so far? What is it giving you?

Comment: When you have multiple items for the same image it should be a list. Meaning: `"858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp": {` should be `"858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp": [` i.e. `{` should be `[` in this case.

Comment: The line `headers = next(reader)` should not be there when you're using `dictreader`.

Comment: I'm just curious, images with `Scratch` an `Dent`, is this for a car insurance company or something?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

Considering your case, I think this is what you are expecting , the below code which I provided will give the exact output what you are looking for.

```
import csv
file = open('out1.csv')
csvreader = csv.reader(file)
header = []
header = next(csvreader)
dic = {}
for row in csvreader:
    if row[0] not in dic:
        dic[row[0]] = []
    dic[row[0]].append({header[i] :row[i]  for i in range(1, len(row))})
print(dic)
```

Hope this solution helps. if not please feel free to comment. Thanks

PS: you can add `int()` for the numbers.

Edit: made the uniq check for image id

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But the code is skipping the first dictionary with id: 1 of the image '858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp'. It is showing only id:2 for the first image. It should show id 1 and 2 for the first image..

Comment: I have edited the code now it works as per your expectation I hope. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mods to your code (assuming input file is tab delimited Excel)

**Code**

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator
import json

def removekey(d, key):
    ' Returns dictionary with entry key removed '
    r = dict(d)
    del r[key]
    return r

with open('out1.csv', 'r') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp, dialect='excel', skipinitialspace=True)
    #headers = next(reader)         # Edit -- handled by reader for dict
    new_dict = {}
    for group, records in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter('image')):
        # Remove image key from each dictionary in records
        new_dict[group] = [removekey(d, 'image') for d in records]
json_object = json.dumps(new_dict, indent = 4)
print(json_object)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Scratch",
            "xMin": "604",
            "xMax": "893",
            "yMin": "230",
            "yMax": "413"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Dent",
            "xMin": "921",
            "xMax": "1146",
            "yMin": "720",
            "yMax": "857"
        }
    ],
    "858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Dent",
            "xMin": "343",
            "xMax": "2323",
            "yMin": "334",
            "yMax": "343"
        }
    ]
}
```

*Note: Input File: (comma delimited values)*

```
image,id,name,xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax
858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp,1,Scratch,604,893,230,413
858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_0_6.webp,2,Dent,921,1146,720,857
858a0246-2f2d-40a9-9bcb-01ab8a93c7f5_BU26844_1630586024_23.webp,1,Dent,343,2323,334,343
```